# return of ajax call from multiple clients are switched

Tags: jquery, ajax, client

I have an server application that runs within (wireless) local area network under a same router.

Each client send ajax call to the server in repetitive manner (using setTimeOut/SetInterval).

The problem is ajax.done() of (let's say) the client 1 receives the return of ajax(jqXhr) which was supposed to be received by the client 2. In the simplified code below, in get_current_chat_index.done() jqxhr of another client's ajax_run_code() is passed to a client.

Does anyone have similar experiences? I know this is a weird situation.

I use mongoose.c for server application on a mobile phone.

```
function updateLog(){
  setTimeout(function(){

  get_current_chat_index()
  .done(function (data,status, xhr) {

    /* I do something here */

    ajax_run_code(' some code ')
    .done(function (data2,status2, xhr2) {

       /* I do some stuff here too */

      updateLog();
    }).fail(function (xhr2, opts2, errorThrown2){
      msg('error', xhr2.responseText );
    });

  }).fail(function (xhr, opts, errorThrown){
    msg('error', xhr.responseText);
  });

}, 1000);
}
```

Comment: That shouldn't be possible. Most likely this is just a logic issue.

Comment: It's more likely that you have a parallel programming issue, maybe a race condition, on the server side.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Are you controlling sessions in any way or simply pulling data from the database to whoever requests it?

Comment: I think the server is responding to whoever requests it? Is that the reason? I didn't code the server application which was not designed for multiple clients.

Comment: @JasonP You were right, there was a problem in the server side where responding to xml data should have been atomic. Thanks!!